# Faster way to set a (PNG) bitmap color instead of pixel by pixel

Tags: java, android, colors

I have some png files that I am applying a color to.  The color changes depending on a user selection.  I change the color via 3 RGB values set from another method.  The png files are a random shape with full transparency outside the shape.  I don't want to modify the transparency, only the RGB value.  Currently, I'm setting the RGB values pixel by pixel (see code below).

I've come to realize this is incredibly slow and possibly just not efficient enough do in an application.  Is there a better way I could do this?

Here is what I am currently doing.  You can see that the pixel array is enormous for an image that takes up a decent part of the screen:

```
public void foo(Component component, ComponentColor compColor, int userColor) {
    int h = component.getImages().getHeight();
    int w = component.getImages().getWidth();
    mBitmap = component.getImages().createScaledBitmap(component.getImages(), w, h, true);

    int[] pixels = new int[h * w];

    //Get all the pixels from the image
    mBitmap[index].getPixels(pixels, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);

    //Modify the pixel array to the color the user selected
    pixels = changeColor(compColor, pixels);

    //Set the image to use the new pixel array
    mBitmap[index].setPixels(pixels, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);
}

public int[] changeColor(ComponentColor compColor, int[] pixels) {
    int red = compColor.getRed();
    int green = compColor.getGreen();
    int blue = compColor.getBlue();
    int alpha;

    for (int i=0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
        alpha = Color.alpha(pixels[i]);
        if (alpha != 0) {
            pixels[i] = Color.argb(alpha, red, green, blue);
        }
    }
    return pixels;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could use an image with a palette? Since you're using one color for everything, that means you can only get 256 possible pixel colors from one input anyway (since the RGB parts will be the same, and only the A part will vary). If your image has a palette with 256 different colors, which only differ in the value for the alpha channel, you would only need to modify the palette, rather than the image data itself.

Comment: I'm either not understanding you or you don't really understand my question.  Each image I want to modify has 2 alpha values, fully transparent and translucent/opaque.  I want to modify the RGB values and keep the alpha values the same.  That said, while I get the concept of a palette, there is no Palette class in android.  What do you suggest I read about?

Comment: @user: Yeah, the idea is that if your PNG file uses a palette, you don't have to modify the pixels, only the palette. Even without SDK support, you could possibly read the PNG file itself as raw data and modify the palette in memory before loading it via a memory stream. It's not a very pretty solution, but it might still bring about a performance improvement if you need it and no one has any better ideas. It should be relatively simple to do, though, since you won't have to deal with compressed data; for details, refer to [the PNG spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-PNG-20031110/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at the functions available in [Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html)?  Something like [extractAlpha](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#extractAlpha%28%29) sounds like it might be useful.  You an also look at the way functions like that are implemented in Android to see how you could adapt it to your particular case, if it doesn't exactly meet your needs.

Comment: Something might be available in Bitmap, but from the sounds of it, extractAlpha won't do it because it doesn't take into account the RGB values of the paint you pass the method (unless it is just undocumented).  Might be worth a shot.  I'll give it a try.

Comment: I didn't mean that it would solve your whole problem, just that it would be useful.  If you read the documentation it talks about combining it with drawCanvas to fill in color information.

Comment: Wow, it worked!!! Unfortunately, only on 2.2 and not 1.6.  Having strange problems on 1.6, but I guess that's another question.

Answer (score 1):

The answer that worked for me was a write up Square did here [Transparent jpegs](https://corner.squareup.com/2013/01/transparent-jpegs.html)

They provide a faster code snippet for doing this exact thing. I tried extractAlpha and it didn't work but Square's solution did. Just modify their solution to instead modify the color bit and not the alpha bit.

i.e.

```
pixels[x] = (pixels[x] & 0xFF000000) | (color & 0x00FFFFFF);
```