# Is there a faster way to process arrays in java android?

Tags: java, android, performance, image, image-processing

I have a bitmap which i am loading each pixel to array. Later i run through each array pixel data and check if the color is RED and change it to BLACK. So if it is a 1024x1024 image, i have to go through a array of 1048576 length. Is there any faster way to process this. Any kind of advice to improve performance is welcome. I basically need to check for a color in image and change it. Below is my code sample.

```
int[] allpixels = new int[myBitmap.getHeight() * myBitmap.getWidth()];

myBitmap.getPixels(allpixels, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0,
                   myBitmap.getWidth(), myBitmap.getHeight());

for (int i = 0; i < myBitmap.getHeight() * myBitmap.getWidth(); i++) {
    if (allpixels[i] == fromColor) {
        allpixels[i] = toColor;
    }
}
Bitmap bitmapCopy = myBitmap.copy(myBitmap.getConfig(), true); 
bitmapCopy.setPixels(allpixels, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0,
                     myBitmap.getWidth(), myBitmap.getHeight());
```

Comment: Sounds like you can use multiple threads here.

Comment: sounds like its your case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251027/faster-way-to-set-a-png-bitmap-color-instead-of-pixel-by-pixel

Answer (score 1):

In your for loop's comparison statement you're getting the height and width and multiplying every time. You can cache that. That should get you a bit of performance boost probably, but otherwise it's just plain a lot of work that your algorithm requires. There's not a ton you can do about it. As suggested in the comment above, you *could* multithread it, but there's no guarantee that you have multiple cores/processors. If performance is that critical, you could consider using RenderScript to do it if you can require ICS. See this [post on image processing](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/levels-in-renderscript.html) for more details.

Actually another approach you might try is to use [setColorFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setColorFilter%28android.graphics.ColorFilter%29). Might need two applications to get a mask with original color then reapply the mask with the new color.